# Mongodb search with space between word

Tags: mongodb

Im searching string in mongo collection using express code as

```
> var criteria = options.searchId;

>     criteria = '.*' + criteria + '.*';

> this.find( { $or: [ { 'content' : { $regex :  criteria , $options :
> 'i' }} , { 'title' : { $regex : criteria , $options : 'i' }} ]} )
```

but when i search `test test` im not getting any result , but the same is present in content column( i think the value is going test%20test) for `test` im getting proper result.My problem  is a statement is not getting searched but a single word in getting searched.

Comment: A little difficult to understand your question, can you clarify or elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
> db.articles.drop()
false
> db.articles.insert({"title": "first", "content": "foo bar"})
> db.articles.insert({"title": "second", "content": "a test test b"})
> db.articles.insert({"title": "third", "content": "only test"})
> db.articles.insert({"title": "test test in title", "content": "lorem ipsum"})
> var query = {"$regex": ".*test test.*", "$options": "i"}
> db.articles.find({"$or": [{"content": query}, {"title": query}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fb789ff00e23295fe08d86"), "title" : "second", "content" : "a test test b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52fb78f5f00e23295fe08d88"), "title" : "test test in title", "content" : "lorem ipsum" }
```

Is this what you expect?

If you have `test%20test` instead of `test test` then it's probably a problem with URL parameter processing in your web framework.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the different encoding of the space characters.
if the encoding of the URL is `test%C2%A0test` it will work
but fails for `test%20test`

refer this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926154/c2a0-and-20-string-comparision) for difference between encode