# c2a0 and 20 string comparision

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I have two utf-8 strings:

- one saved as variable in php file (saved in UTF-8)
- another gets externally from another with regular expression.

When I compare those two same space-separated strings, the result is false, meaning that they are not the same.

- The string I saved as a variable is rendered as `20` with `bin2hex` (ascii encoded space symbol)
- The string I got externally, processed with `mb_strtolower($string, 'utf-8')` is rendered as `c2a0` with `bin2hex` (utf-8 space)

My questions is:

1. Why when I save in utf-8 string not fully encoded as utf-8 (meaning space in ascii)?
2. How to get rid of that problem?

Comment: `c2a0` is a [no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) whereas `20` is a [space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm).

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments `c2a0` is a [no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) and `20` is normal [space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)

Since you can see the problem in bin2hex you could:

```
$str = hex2bin(str_replace('c2a0', '20', bin2hex($str)));
```

or to put that another way:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\xc2\xa0~', ' ', $str); // typo corrected
```